# SOLVED: Interpretation of a coercive function

Tags: real-analysis, limits, nonlinear-optimization

A continuous function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$ is called **coercive** if 
$$\lim_{\|x\|\to\infty} f(x)=\infty.$$

I'm confused as to how to interpret this limit. I have the 2 following possible interpretations, which I don't think are equivalent.

1. For each $N\in \mathbb{R}$, there is some $M>0$ such that $\|x\|>M\implies f(x)>N$.
2. For each (not necessarily continous) path $p:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}^n$, where 
   $$\lim_{t\to\infty} \|p(t)\|=\infty,$$
   we have that $$\lim_{t\to\infty}f(p(t))=\infty.$$

I believe it to be the 2nd statement, but the textbook I'm reading seems to use the 1st statement. Can anyone tell me which one is correct or if they're equivalent? Thanks.

There are uncountably many choices for $p$, so we can't necessarily compute the $M$-value for each of them, as the collection of $M$'s might not be bounded.

**Solution**

$(1)\implies (2)$ is obvious.

For $(2)\implies (1)$, assume (1) fails. There take some $N$ such that for each $M$, there is some $p(M)$ such that $||p(M)||>M$ and $f(p(M))\le N$. Then the first limit in (2) holds, but the 2nd limit is $\le N$, so (2) fails.

Comment: Your two interpretations are equivalent.  Usually, (1) is taken as the definition, and (2) is a theorem.

Comment: Why is it equivalent? For example, viewing $\mathbb{R}^2$ as $\mathbb{C}$, and taking $f(z)= |z^\theta|$ where $\theta\in  (0,2\pi]$ is the complex argument of $z$. I know this is discontinuous on $[0,\infty)$, the nonnegative real axis. So maybe continuity makes them equivalent? If so, How? No matter how big $|z|$ gets, we can always stick $z$ slightly above the real axis for $f(z)$ to not exceed the given threshold.

Comment: Actually we can take $\theta$ to be the unique number in $[0,\pi]$ such that $z$ or $\bar{z}$ have argument $\theta$. Define $f(0)=0$, and $f(z)=|z^{\theta+1}|$ for $z\neq0$. Now we have a continuous function that satisfy (2) but not (1)

Comment: Since $\theta + 1 \in \mathbb{R}$, if $|z| > 1$ we have $$ f(z) = |z^{\theta + 1}| = |z|^{\theta + 1} \ge |z|. $$  Fix $N > 0$.  If $|z| > N$, then $f(z) > N$.  This seems to be property (1), no?

Comment: You figured it out!  Good!  I had plans of writing up a solution this evening, after I finish up some other things, but I think that it might be a better idea for you to take the answer out of the question and post it as an answer yourself.  Note, also, that you can use `$\| \cdot \|$` to typeset the double vertical bars correctly: $\| \cdot \|$.

Comment: Yeah. One of the situations where the equivalence of the contrapositive saves a big deal of headaches.